# Is there a way to swipe from one fragment to another using navigation graphs?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-architecture-navigation

So I have a navigation graph with 2 fragments ( FragA, FragB ) and I want to be able to move from one to the other by swiping either to the left or right. I have an action that connects FragA to FragB and I have used it to fade from FragA to FragB by clicking a button. However, I want to be able to left swipe on FragA to reach FragB and reverse to return.

edit: I'm trying to use Navigation instead of ViewPager because FragA is also connected to another fragment through the navigation graph. Right now I am trying to combine the navigation component and the viewpager but I'd like a solution with only the navigation component.

Comment: Navigation does not have a UI. As a result, it does not handle swipe gestures. The developers of the Navigation component documented two solutions for this: `ViewPager` (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view) and `ViewPager2` (https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2). You could try to do your own gesture detection (e.g., via `GestureDetector`) and just [animate the transitions between the fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions).

Comment: try view pager 2: https://www.boltuix.com/2022/10/tablayout-onboarding-screens-with.html

Answer (score 0):

So apparently using a ViewPager alongside the navigation was not so complicated. Here's how I did it.

- Added an androidx.viewpager2.widgit.ViewPager2 in my activity_main.xml
- Added a java class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter
- - I used the default constructor that took FragmentManager and Lifecycle as arguments
- - Implemented methods
- - - createFragment returns FragA for position = 0 and FragB for position = 2
- - - getcount returns 2 (cuz I only have 2 fragments)

In MainActivity onCreate

- Created a final instance of ViewPager2 and set it to the ViewPager2 in my activity_main.xml
- Created a new instance of PagerAdapter giving getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle() as arguments
- set the viewpager adapter to the pageradapter

This gave me exactly what I wanted, just not how I thought I needed it.

You can stop over here but there is one little issue that crops up now. If you press the back button expecting to undo a navigation action in the navgraph, the app will instead take the action pressing the back button would expect to at the main activity level.

Simply copy this into the fragments of the navigation graph where you want that pressing back should undo the navigation action that brought you to

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            popNavBackStack();
        }
    };
    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
}

public void popNavBackStack(){
    NavController journalNavHost = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
    journalNavHost.popBackStack();
}
```

Comment: The new separate possibly workable issue that arises is that now when I press back I want my navigation component within the ViewPager2 to react to it if ViewPager2 is showing position 0. But it seems the ViewPager is intercepting it and minimizing the app.